# Help with Makefile for C program

Tags: compiling, make, c

I'm trying to generate a new library that includes another one I have created previously.

In my current folder I have my source files inside a src folder and my headers inside an include folder.

This what I've done until now:

```makefile
NAME        := mainlibrary.a

SRCS        :=  $(wildcard src/*.c)
OBJS        := $(SRCS:.c=.o) $(wildcard lib/*.o)
S_LIB       := lib/secondarylibrary.a

CC          := gcc
CFLAGS      := -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Iinclude -Ilib
    
RM          := rm -f
MAKEFLAGS   := --no-print-directory
    
all: $(S_LIB) $(NAME)
    
$(NAME): $(OBJS) $(S_LIB)
    ar rcs $(NAME) $(OBJS) $(S_LIB)

$(S_LIB):
    $(MAKE) -C lib

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJS) $(wildcard lib/*.o)

fclean: clean
    $(RM) $(NAME) $(S_LIB)

re:
    $(MAKE) fclean
    $(MAKE) all

.PHONY: all bonus clean fclean re
```

Now, when I try to compile my program with

```shell
gcc main.c -L. -lmainlibrary.a -Iinclude -Ilib.
```

I can't do it unless I specify the secondary library which defeats the whole purpose as I'm trying to have that library already inside my main library.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding you. You've shown us a `makefile` but if you're running `gcc…` directly then you're not using it. And what do you mean by `"_I'm trying to have that library already inside my main library_"? Libraries don't contain libraries

Comment: A library as part of a library... does that even work? Does the linker search for symbols recursively in libraries?

Comment: You are adding an ar archive into another, not the .o files from one into another. Take a look at this answer for how to merge ar archives: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821916/how-to-merge-two-ar-static-libraries-into-one

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone, I was indeed mistaken thinking I could sort of join the two libraries together. What I've done is instead take the object files generated in the subdirectory and use them to generate the second library

Comment: Please write an answer as to what you did.  It would benefit other readers and "close" this question

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot everyone, I was indeed mistaken thinking I could sort of join the two libraries together. What I've done is instead take the object files generated in the subdirectory and use them along with my current object files to generate the second library. It seems so obvious now...

EDIT: As requested, I'll explain what I did:
I can't use secondlibrary.a and just merge it with main library.a

Now, I do have a makefile inside lib folder that generates all the object files out of all the .c files I have in that folder before creating secondlibrary.a.

This line in my makefile:
$(S_LIB):
$(MAKE) -C lib

Basically says, go into lib folder and use "make" command to activate that makefile.

As I already have all my object files generated in that folder, all I need to is used those along with the ones I'm using for my mainlibrary.a

I changed the previous makefile I posted to this:

```
NAME        := libftprintf.a
SUBDIR      := libft
SRCDIR      := src
INCDIR      := include

SRCS        := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c)
OBJS        := $(SRCS:$(SRCDIR)/%.c=%.o)
INCLUDES    := -I$(INCDIR) -Ilibft

CC          := clang
CFLAGS      := -Wall -Wextra -Werror $(INCLUDES)

RM          := rm -f
MAKEFLAGS   := --no-print-directory

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OBJS) $(SUBDIR)/libft.a
    ar rcs $(NAME) $(OBJS) $(wildcard $(SUBDIR)/*.o)

$(SUBDIR)/libft.a:
    $(MAKE) -C $(SUBDIR)

%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJS)
    $(MAKE) -C $(SUBDIR) clean

fclean:
    $(RM) $(NAME) $(OBJS)
    $(MAKE) -C $(SUBDIR) fclean

re:
    $(MAKE) fclean
    $(MAKE) all

.PHONY: all clean fclean re $(SUBDIR)/libft.a
```

Now $(NAME) which is my mainlibrary.a depends on the object files in the current directory and the object files inside my subdirectory. Please keep in mind that "$(SUBDIR)/libft.a"(my secondlibrary.a) wouldn't really be necessary to create but it was a requirement for my assignment so I left it there, this also allows me to take advantage of the makefile that's already inside that subdirectory.

Comment: Please [edit] this to *explain* exactly what you did  at a level of detail that will actually help the next person who makes this mistake.